# RequestDispatcher#forward not just render a page?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, rendering

In my web.xml, I set up a servlet like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>forward</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.Forward</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>forward</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/f/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`test.Forward#doGet` is implemented as

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("target.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

When visiting **localhost:8080/project/f/anypath**, server crashes due to a stack overflow error.

It seems that `RequestDispatcher#forward` sets up another request to **/f/target.jsp**, and then `test.Forward#doGet` is called again, and then again. I somehow misunderstood `RequestDispatcher#forward` that I thought it as just render a page.

So, are there any methods that just render JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet path is /f/*, and you're redirecting to a file that is on that path, most likely unintentionally:

```
/f/target.jsp
```

As a result, this creates an endless loop as your servlet keeps calling itself again and again and again.

If you want to redirect to the JSP, I'm assuming it's located in another folder like a /jsp/target.jsp location?  If so, then make sure you include the full path:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/target.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

When you leave out the `/`, the request is forwarded relative to the current requestURI.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Hmm, I still wonder if there is pure page rendering in Java EE, or even 3rd party page rendering utilities, like Mako in Python.

Comment: Pure page rendering? Can you elaborate?

Comment: For example, an interface like `String render(String jspPath, HttpServletRequest request)`. A call to `render("index.jsp", request)` will return a string "<html><body>Hello, world", and then we can use `response.getWriter().println` to send the page content to the client.

Comment: Forwards are invoked internally by the servlet. There is no request from the browser. Unless I'm missing something, a forward is exactly what you want. That is, unless you plan on doing some really low-level stuff with the raw JSP content before processing it, but that would be something one would do for fun/research, not for a production app.